# Assembly MIPS evaluate difference with only BEQ

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi have to code this loop:

```
for($6=10;$6!=0;$6--){ 
    $7=$6; 
}
```

but with some conditions. I can only use `BEQ` and must assume that the initial value of each register is the number of the register.

How can evaluate that difference only using `BEQ`?

I've made this

```
main:
    add   $6,$5,$5
    for:
        add     $7,$6,$0
        sub     $6,$6,$1
        beq     $6,for
```

but I'm stuck on the verification.

Comment: Coding that "loop" consists of setting `$6` to `0` and `$7` to `1`, surely?

Comment: surely. This is an initial step. Them we have to transform it on MIPS machine code. I know how to do the last step but not the first (the most easy) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set $6 equal to 10. Why give $6 an initial value of 6 when you're
   just going to overwrite it?
2. Enter your loop and set $7 to $6.
3. Decrement $6 and jump to the next label if $6 equals zero, otherwise
   jump back to the start of the loop.

The code:

```
li $6, 10
for:
    move $7, $6
    subi $6, $6, 1
    beq $6, $0, end
    j for
end:
```